# Perform operation in response to insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out if I can write an automatic script/function/event in SQL Server to deal with the following:

"When new row added to Table X, copy Table Y rows to Table Z"

Does SQL Server handle this sort of functionality, or do I have to do this in an outside program like C#?

Thanks a lot - kcross

EDIT: A bit more detail on the problem..
Table X = a normal database table, stored rows of, lets say, user information. 
Table Y = a database table of fixed rows, that stores live data (like GPS coordinates of plane)
Table Z = used to store historical information on whenever a new user is added to Table X.  For example, say a new row is added to Table X.  The problem requires the live data at the time that the new row is added to Table X.  This table will store that data, and the corresponding new row and data in this table is linked by a identifying number.

So when new row is added to Table X, create a script that automatically copies that live data for Y into a new row Table Z [and also store the corresponding identifier so that Table X's new row can be matched to Table Z's corresponding row(s)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trigger for this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CopyYToZ
ON dbo.X
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.Z SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.Y WHERE ...
END
GO
```

I'd give more specifics, but you didn't really provide any in the question, so...

Comment: Yea, I know it was pretty vague... To be honest, there isn't much more to it (not a lot of logic or anything).

If I create this trigger, it lasts forever ya? (ie if server is restarted, I don't have to recreate the trigger do I?)

Comment: I don't know about any database system where triggers have to be recreated after a reboot.. 
About your first question.. Nothing last forever :-p

Comment: one last question, what does SET NOCOUNT ON; do?

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1226/set-nocount-on-improves-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance/

Comment: Just note that the insert above will copy all rows from Y even though some of them may have been copied previously. So I expect Z will grow exponentially as rows are added to X or Y.

Comment: Yea, basically table Y is some live data, and whenever something is added to X I need to copy that live data over somewhere (table Z) to store the matching live data for that new row in X (table Y never grows, is only overwritten). 

Using that method above, how would I access (in the code) the values of that updated row. For example, my table Z has a column that I want to store the ID of the new row in table X, how would I script: Z.matchingID = X.newrow's ID?

Comment: If you're inserting into Z, I don't know how you're going to match Z.MatchingID since it doesn't exist until after you've done the insert into Z. Do you mean Y? Can you please update the question with details about what data is getting inserted into X, and what data from Y then gets inserted into Z? Adding a word problem as a comment isn't going to help me, you, or future readers.

Comment: one note of caution...if you have a system that does everything else with stored procs and you add one trigger, make sure to document. The next developer (which may be you in 6months) will probably forget to go looking at the triggers.

Comment: Yes @Bill that's a good point. I'd actually recommend handling this logic in a stored procedure if you're already restricting write access to dbo.X via a stored procedure, however the OP may not be and it may not be safe to rely on that anyway (folks with sufficient access can bypass your procedure or the trigger, but the latter is a little more work and has to be malicious).

Comment: Hi Aaron, I asked another question along the same topic that has a bit more detail (I hope!).  Any help is much appreciated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690096/insert-statement-combining-table-data-and-variable-in-trigger